# Purpose of serializing/deserializing users into a session when using PassportJS?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

What is the purpose of serializing/deserializing users into the session when using PassportJS? I worked with JSP before and there seems to be no notion of these things.

Answer (score 0):

It controls how the user instance gets saved to your session store (such as [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis)).

I'm no expert on JSP, but I imagine there's some sort of ISerializable interface that classes must implement, which would be a rough equivalent.