# Serialize and Deserialize User — passport.js

Tags: passport.js

What do the passport.js functions passport.serializeUser and passport.serializeUser do? Is this an example of serialization as it is described on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Answer (score 7):

Yep.

These allow the user's data to be saved and retrieved from [a session store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640117/purpose-of-serializing-deserializing-users-into-a-session-when-using-passportjs).  This could be memory, redis, or any other database.

If you like reading the source, you will see that `passport.session` is involved as it [will restore login state from a session](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/authenticator.js#L199) and the `deserializeUser` gets the user information from that.

The code that follows after `Authenticator.prototype.session` defines the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` methods that let us add our own serializers/deserializers.

Comment: Are you suggesting universally bypassing the npm docs and to only look at the source code in GitHub?  This approach makes using npm packages very difficult.  I think the OP was looking for someone who already understands the source to help explain it to them. When someone asks me how to change their wallpaper in Windows, I don't generally start by having them disassemble the binaries.

Comment: @JonathanRys - that's a bit of a stretch. First, this question is three+ years old, and the docs have matured.  Second, I link to an answer by the Passport author.  And finally, I start the third paragraph with "If you like reading the source..." to indicate that this is just additional info.  Not sure where you get the idea I think anything 'universal' about docs.  :\